# How to make sure that `range` includes zero?

Tags: python, loops, range

I want the most elegant way to get multiples of a number n in between -100 and 100, where 100 just represents another long formula.
`range(-100, 100, n)` skips over 0 when n is say 30.

n=30
want: -90, -60, -30, 0, 30, 60, 90
`range(-100, 100, n)` yields -100, -70, -40, -10, 20, 50, 80

currently, I'm using

```
temp = 100//n
intervals = [i*n for i in range(-temp, temp)]
plt.gca().set_xticks(intervals, minor=True)
```

as you can see this is very ugly code and I don't like this.

I just want a more elegant way to do this (and preferable doesn't make the line more than 80 characters long)

```
plt.gca().set_xticks(something, minor=True)
```

Comment: You might be interested in [`numpy.linspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) which takes arguments `(start, step, num)` or [`numpy.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) which accepts `(start, stop, step)` whichever of those you prefer.

Comment: `range(-(100 // n * n), 100 // n * n, n)`?

Comment: or `range(-(100 // n * n), 100, n)` if you want `90` to be in the result

Comment: @AzatIbrakov, the `100` here represents a long formula, so having it twice in a line would make the line too long.. :'(  
But I think this is the more elegant solution I've seen here so far, no listcomp or anything. If you post it as an answer I'll upvote and accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can prove that all `x < 0` that go through `0` with step `n` satisfy following formula:

```
y = n * x
```

where `x` - some negative whole number.
If we want it to be not lesser than `-100` then we can set

```
x = ceil(-100 / n) * n
```

finally we can show that `ceil(-100 / n) = -floor(100 / n)` which is `-(100 // n)` in Python (note `-` going outside parentheses due to [operators precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)).

So for `range` going through `0` with step `n` with `start` not lesser than `-100` and `stop` not greater than `100` we have

```py
range(-(100 // n) * n, 100, n)
```

example:

```
>>> n=30
>>> list(range(-(100 // n) * n, 100, n))
[-90, -60, -30, 0, 30, 60, 90]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution (`range` based) for integers:

```
def mk_zero_centred_range(xmin, xmax, xstep):
    assert xmin <= 0 and xmax > 0 and xstep > 0
    return [-x for x in range(0, -xmin, xstep)[1:][::-1]] + list(range(0, xmax, xstep))

print(mk_zero_centred_range(-5, 5, 1)) #[-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print(mk_zero_centred_range(-7, 9, 2)) #[-6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

With numpy (`np.arange` based) for floats:

```
import numpy as np

def mk_zero_centred_arange(xmin, xmax, xstep):
    assert xmin <= 0 and xmax > 0 and xstep > 0
    return np.r_[-np.arange(0, -xmin, xstep)[1:][::-1],np.arange(0, xmax, xstep)]

print(mk_zero_centred_arange(-3, 5, 0.4))
# [-2.8 -2.4 -2. -1.6 -1.2 -0.8 -0.4  0. 0.4 0.8 1.2 1.6 2. 2.4 2.8 3.2 3.6 4. 4.4 4.8]
print(mk_zero_centred_arange(0, 5, 0.3))
# [0.  0.3 0.6 0.9 1.2 1.5 1.8 2.1 2.4 2.7 3.  3.3 3.6 3.9 4.2 4.5 4.8]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer,  I can see that it is very rigorous with the assert to check the args! maybe I'll resort to an extra function if it looks too ugly as I work on my code

Comment: In this case `assert` is just a way to show how to use this function properly. Passing negative `xstep` or `xmax` leads to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a set?

```py
>>> sorted(set(range(0,-100,-30)[::-1] + list(range(0,100, 30))))
[-90, -60, -30, 0, 30, 60, 90]
```